# Show First Post in Full, Followed by Truncated Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, truncate

I am trying to write a custom default loop for my blog that will display the first post in full, then have the following posts appear in truncated format with a thumbnail of featured image. I have tried everything I can think of, but cannot figure out how to properly parse the loop. I tried the code from the Wordpress forums, but neither work.

```
<?php
if (is_front_page() && ++$count == 1) {
   the_content();
} else {
   $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,80); ?>
}
```

and

```
<?php
$count = 0;
if ($count > 0) {
   $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,80);
} else {
     the_content();
}
$count++;
?>
```

I have been working on this for weeks. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Please show the full loop, including the while loop

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a "default" loop I'm sure you can use this variable, `$current_post`, which is defined inside the Loop.

```
<?php 
if (is_front_page() && $wp_query->current_post === 1) {
   the_content();
} else {
   $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,80);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$current_post` be `$wp_query->current_post`

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php $i+=1; ?>
 <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
 <div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></div> 
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <?php if($i<2): the_content(); ?>
 <?php else: ?>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
 ...
```